# file i/o permission issue (Android emulator)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm having some trouble getting to the ICS emulator to dump data into files (or even create them). I've built the emulator with 'rw' permission and verified that 'adb push' does work (with read only permission, this used to fail). The emulator just seems to run this piece of code but never creates the files. I've tried creating in /system/etc and /mnt/sdcard (and using my own sdcard.img file in the boot command). Any idea how I can get past this?

Comment: huh? what "*piece of code*"? /me stares blankly at your question. My suggestion - Include a bit more info than this. Also, you cannot write to `/system/etc` as that's protected unless you are rooted and have remounted the system as rewrite-able.

Comment: This is the piece of code I added (in libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java). I don't get any exceptions, but the file is not generated...      try
        {
        f0 = new FileWriter("/mnt/sdcard/cts_date0.txt");
        f0.write("cts0\n");
        f0.write("\n");
        f0.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){}

Comment: this is about an app or about terminal commands ? because if it's about an app you probably need to check your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
f0.flush();
```

before

```
f0.close();
```

to ensure the buffered data is writen do file.

add the following in the catch() part of your code:

```
catch (IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this will print to the catlog the what is the issue.

Confirm that you have the sdcard ceated in AVD Manager. Open it and check the following:

[image: AVD Manager]

Comment: No, flush didn't help either. This code (in SimpleDateFormat.java) is built as part of core.apk and is exercised whenever I run a CTS test. The same file i/o code does generate the file when run on our device, but fails only in the emulator. This time I even tried creating my own sdcard.img file and passing that when kicking off the emulator

Comment: Thanks Luis for the additional info. I added the printStackTrace() call, but don't see any further info. Will this show up in logcat? I don't have eclipse, just using a shell to build the emulator. Also, my sdcard image size is pretty big: -rwxrwxrwx   1 dev dev 536870912 2012-10-08 16:52 mysdcard.img

Comment: Yes, it goes to the logcat. You realy need to check it if you want to know what's going on. By the way, confirm that you have added the permission to write to external storage in you manifest.xml.

Comment: I have created 2 logs, one with file i/o & the other without & comparing right now. Is there any way to attach the logcat logs? The emulator does have write permission and i've checked it by running "touch abc.txt" under adb shell in /mnt/sdcard. I'm wondering if this is a permissions issue (where in it works in the command line but can't create the file from the java files)?

Comment: Thanks, I found the messages in logcat, it does throw the permission denied error: D/InstrumentationCtsTestRunner(  711): Now executing : libcore.java.text.SimpleDateFormatTest
I/TestRunner(  711): started: testNonDstZoneNameWithDstTimestamp(libcore.java.text.SimpleDateFormatTest)
W/System.err(  711): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/cts_date0.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err(  711):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
W/System.err(  711):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)

Comment: What about the permission to write to external storage in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: The test apk is called android.core.tests.libcore.package.libcore.apk and I found it's manifest file under ~/cts/tests/co‌​re/libcore/libcore where I added this line & rebuilt: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> but still get the same error

Comment: edit your original question and copy the content of manifest.xml file in there. It looks like you have added the line in the wrong tag.

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.core.tests.libcore.package.libcore">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application>
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

    <instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationCtsTestRunner"
                     android:targetPackage="android.core.tests.runner"
                     android:label="cts framework tests"/>

</manifest>
~

Comment: This don't look like your application manifest. If you are building a standard android aplplication you need to have in the file a <activity> tag with your application name and intent-filter. Try to find another manifest file, otherwise I don't know what else to investigate.

Comment: I actually confirmed that this is where it picks up the Android.mk & the AndroidManifest.xml files. As I said earlier, I'm building one of the CTS apks to debug the path in the emulator vs our device. Thanks a lot for your assistance, really appreciate it